# Resetting object in java

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android Game. Entire gameplay is in "Gameplay" class. The problem is when i want to have start again option and i have no idea how to remove "mg" object from "Gameplay" class and make a new one. Here is my code:

```
package com.PJA.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class GameScreen extends BaseScreen {
    static short state=1;
    Gameplay mg;
    Menu mm;
    LostScreen ls;
    public GameScreen(Gra game) {
        super(game);
        mm=new Menu();
        mg=new Gameplay();
        ls=new LostScreen();
    }

    public void update() {
        if(state==1)    mm.live();
        if(state==2)    mg.live();
        if(state==3)    ls.live();

        Gdx.app.log("CurrentState: ", Integer.toString(state));
    }

    public void drau(SpriteBatch sb) {
        if(state==1)    mm.show(sb);
        if(state==2)    mg.show(sb);    
        if(state==3)    ls.show(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new one and set it to `mg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mg = new Gameplay()
```

this will create a new instance that will replace the old one (which will eventually be garbage-collected)

Another option, which is way more verbose, is to write a `.reset()` method that sets all fields of `Gameplay` to their initial values. This will give you better control over which fields you want to reset, but if you want everything - just create a new instance of `Gameplay`

Answer (score 0):

It's often a bad idea to initialize all fields in the constructor. While it feels natural, it limits reuse. It's often better to create a dedicated `init()` or `reset()` method:

```
public GameScreen(Gra game) {
    super(game);

    reset();
}

public void reset() {
    mm=new Menu();
    mg=new Gameplay();
    ls=new LostScreen();
}
```